# how do i make my digital waiting queue management system update to the current token automatically in every device?

Tags: javascript, queue

(Sorry for poor english, it is not my first language)
The digital queue management i made for a paper needs to be updated manually by every device, i imagine i will need to enter back-end territory so the program is already running in a server, but i'm not well versed in any back-end tecnology and dont know how they can comunicate with the work i have done. my objective is to have the token to update in every machine automaticaly

This is what i managed to do, a friend of mine recomended me the jquery-3.3.1.min package to help

Thank you for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Queue</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="barraTop">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="container page">
        <div class="row barraSuperior">
            <div class="col-xs-11" style="text-align: right;"><p></p>
                <span class="uespiTexto">Waiting queue</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="senhaAtual">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1" style="text-align: right;"><br><br>
                        <span class="senhaAtualTexto">TOKEN &nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5"  style="text-align: left;">
                        <span id="senhaAtualNumero">0000</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="senhaNormal" value="0000">
                    <input type="hidden" id="senhaPrioridade" value="P000">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 ultimaSenha">
                <br>
                <span id="ultimaSenhaTexto">LAST TOKEN</span><br>
                <span>Token </span>
                <span id="ultimaSenhaNumero">0000</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <audio id="audioChamada" src="audio/chamada.wav"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

```
let filename = "senhas.txt";
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("body").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var senhaAtual   = $("#senhaAtualNumero");
        var senhaNormal  = $("#senhaNormal");
        var senhaPrior   = $("#senhaPrioridade");
        var ultimaSenha  = $("#ultimaSenhaNumero");
        var audioChamada = $("#audioChamada");
        
        if(e.keyCode == 39){
            ultimaSenha.html(senhaAtual.html());
            senha = parseInt(senhaNormal.val()) + 1;
            senhaAtual.html(pad(senha, 4));
            senhaNormal.val(pad(senha, 4));
            audioChamada.trigger("play");
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 65){
            senha = parseInt(senhaNormal.val()) - 1;
            senhaAtual.html(pad(senha, 4));
            senhaNormal.val(pad(senha, 4));
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38){
            ultimaSenha.html(senhaAtual.html());
            senha = parseInt(senhaPrior.val().replace("P","")) + 1;
            senhaAtual.html("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            senhaPrior.val("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            audioChamada.trigger("play");
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 83){
            senha = parseInt(senhaPrior.val().replace("P","")) - 1;
            senhaAtual.html("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            senhaPrior.val("P" + pad(senha, 3));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You will need to look at the server's capabilities. They probably offer PHP. A really basic version would just be reading and writing to a text file on the server. After you get a feeling for that, then look into web sockets. A web socket would allow the server to auto notify the devices with the new token

Comment: will i need to rewrite the entire code in php?

Comment: You can keep what you have for the front end. You will eventually need to add more to it like ajax to submit the data to the server to save etc.. But I would focus on learning server side first.